# Flutter Unable to load contents of file list '?target Support/Pods

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I created new flutter app, and run it and got.
I tried "pod install" but still getting this issue

[image]

Actually ,
First I created flutter project and then I try to run "Pod Install"
but it was showing "Pod file not found",
so I executed "Pod init" I got a pod file, I edit that Pod file as previous running project.
and then I performed "Pod Install", everything installed fine.

But when I try to run  project I am getting this issue.

Comment: what is the deployment target of your application?

Comment: Its 11.00 , I created another new flutter project but still getting this.

Comment: make sure that deployment target in runner and pod file are same also make sure that you have assigned a development team to your project